# Google play returns empty purchase data

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {        
    if (requestCode == 228) { // part which procces iap purchases 
        try {
            Bundle response = mService.getBuyIntent(3, getPackageName(), lastSku, "inapp", security); //lastSku - name (id) of element which is sold
            { //this part was taken in figure braces because I don't need it. I just only want to know which data I receive here
                Bundle ownedItems = mService.getPurchases(3, getPackageName(), "inapp", null);
                int responseCode = ownedItems.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE"); //==0
                if (responseCode == 0) {
                    ArrayList<String> ownedSkus =
                            ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST"); // contains 0 elements
                    ArrayList<String>  purchaseDataList =
                            ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA_LIST"); // also 0
                    ArrayList<String>  signatureList =
                            ownedItems.getStringArrayList("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE"); // also 0
                    String continuationToken =
                            ownedItems.getString("INAPP_CONTINUATION_TOKEN"); //==null

                    for (int i = 0; i < purchaseDataList.size(); ++i) { //does not work because of 0 elements
                        String purchaseData = purchaseDataList.get(i);
                        String signature = signatureList.get(i);
                        String sku = ownedSkus.get(i);

                        // do something with this purchase information
                        // e.g. display the updated list of products owned by user
                    }

                    // if continuationToken != null, call getPurchases again
                    // and pass in the token to retrieve more items
                }
            }
            int code = response.getInt("RESPONSE_CODE");//==0
            if (code == 0) {
                String signature = response.getString("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE"); //==null
                String s = response.getString("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA"); //==null
                JSONObject purchaseData = new JSONObject(s); //here it throws NullPointerException
                purchaseData.getString("orderId");
                purchaseData.getString("packageName");
                purchaseData.getString("productId");
                purchaseData.getString("purchaseTime");
                purchaseData.getString("purchaseState");
                purchaseData.getString("developerPayload");
                purchaseData.getString("purchaseToken");


            } else if (code != 1) { //never got in this part of code
                Toast.makeText(this,"IAP ERROR " + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        } catch (RemoteException e) { //never got in this part of code
            Toast.makeText(this,"Connection error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (JSONException e) { //never got in this part of code
            Toast.makeText(this,"Response parse error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    simpleFacebook.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data); //also I have facebook auth in my activity
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I runned my app on the phone, on which the main google account is the same as developer account. Also I have written my account in developer console -> settings -> info about account -> test account and I set there to return LICENSED
When I run my app I see "Publisher can't buy this"
The app isn't published

p.s. also. When I get "check your internet connection" I also recive 0-elements ArrayLists and null Strings. Is it normal?